# How to find that website is using microformats or not?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, microformats

friends

I have to find that a given(any) website is using microformats or  not,how to do that?I'd seen how to use micro format but still not getting which are those exceptional tag,used only to make
microforts.should I search for hcard or vcard??or span classes I am not getting pls help me.
does google provide any api for that, I searched google webmaster as well.I am using c#,asp.net.

Comment: I 'd seen some more ,example I ,think I should search for hcard ,and vcard class ,am I correct??

Answer (score 0):

microformats.org has all the information you are searching for regarding class names, etc. You can use this bookmarklet to extract vcards on a page:

```
javascript:location.href='http://suda.co.uk/projects/microformats/hcard/get-contact.php?uri='+escape(location.href)
```

However that's only going to show vcards, so if you're testing a page and it has no vcard, that doesn't mean that it does not have other microformats on the page elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so programmatically, you can write code to parse/grep page content for a sequence of DIV and SPAN elements with the classes characteristic of the microformat you are looking for.

To do so manually (as a human), the QA process I use is:
Install one of the browser plugins detailed at http://microformats.org/wiki/Main_Page and browse to the page you want to verify... the browser will detect any present microformats on the page and display the information.